# Displaying video in a web view causes Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-webview

I'm trying to display a video given a url. Below is part of the layout which contains the `WebView`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        ......
        ......

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ......

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>

            ......

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is the how I display the video:

```
if(url != null && mVideo != null) {
    WebSettings settings = mVideo.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String videoFrame = "<html><head><style type=\'text/css\'>body{margin:auto;text-align:center;}</style></head>" +
                    "<body><iframe width=\"90%%\" height=\"100%%\" src=\"https:" + url + "\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></body></html>";

    mVideo.loadData(videoFrame, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

While this is the error that I'm encountering:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                             at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.getDefaultVideoPoster(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:1181)
                                                             at org.chromium.android_webview.DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler$1.run(DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler.java:39)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

What's hard about this is that, sometimes this occurs, sometimes it does not. So it's really hard to pinpoint the problem.

Aside from this, I'm also encountering the problem reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206331), though it doesn't seem to affect how I display the video.

Comment: I've been getting the same problem lately.  I'm really stumped at what causes it, but cleaning the project seems to be a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else stumbles upon this crash, here is a **possible** fix:

The error is caused by getDefaultVideoPoster() method throwing an exception due to some reason. The idea is to override that method and wrap the code into a try/catch block. If the default method fails, we build a fallback video poster using one of our drawables. The code is in Kotlin.

```
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun getDefaultVideoPoster(): Bitmap? {
            return try {
                super.getDefaultVideoPoster()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.default_video_poster)
            }
        }
    }
```

default_video_poster is a drawable which acts as a fallback video poster. Here is what I use if you are in a hurry and can't make your own:

[image: Default video poster darwable]